# Изменение плагина woocommerce для wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В плагине Woocommerce для Wordpress хочу поменять html разметку блоков и тексты заголовков. Как и где надо искать?

Искал так - в инспекторе находил название стилей, и использовал поиск в исходных файлах Wordpress с помощью редактора notepad++. В PHP файлах менял текст, строки, потом заливал всё это на тестовый хостинг. При этом в большинстве случаев вообще ничего не происходило, иногда удавалось "сломать" сайт и приходилось откатываться назад.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод документации "[**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)"

Файлы шаблонов WooCommerce содержат разметку для клиентского интерфейса и HTML-писем вашего магазина. Изучив их содержимое, можно заметить, что все эти файлы содержат хуки, позволяющие вам добавлять или перемещать содержимое без необходимости править эти файлы напрямую. Подобный метод правки содержимого без изменения исходных файлов позволяет избежать проблем, связанных с обновлением системы.

Файлы шаблонов находятся в папке `/woocommerce/templates/`.

Посмотреть структуру папок и содержимое файлов для версии `v2.5.0` можно [**тут**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/2.5.0/templates).
Полный список версий WooCommerce и соответствующих им файлов шаблонов можно найти по ссылке на документацию в самом начале ответа.

Чтобы не возникало проблем с обновлением WooCommerce, файлы шаблонов следует изменять путем их переопределения.

Скопируйте файлы шаблонов соответствующей версии WooCommerce внутрь вашей темы в подпапку `/woocommerce`, сохраняя оригинальную структуру папок, исключая подпапку `/templates/`.

Например, чтобы переопределить уведомления о заказе для администратора, скопируйте

```
woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php
```

в папку

```
ваша_тема/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php
```

Скопированный файл теперь переопределяет оригинальный.

> **Внимание**: если в вашей теме есть файл `woocommerce.php`,
>   вы не сможете переопределить `woocommerce/archive-product.php`
>   файлом внутри вашей темы, поскольку файл `woocommerce.php`
>   имеет приоритет над всеми остальными файлами шаблонов.
>   Это сделано для предотвращения проблем с отображением информации.

Не редактируйте файлы шаблонов напрямую, поскольку все сделанные вами изменения будут потеряны после обновления системы.

### Обновление

Шаблон формы поиска находится в папке

```
woocommerce/templates/product-searchform.php
```

Скопируйте его в

```
ваша_тема/woocommerce/product-searchform.php
```

И изменяйте так, как вам надо.

Comment: Пример: 
вот мой тестовый сайт http://supershop.imperiasoblazna.ru/
надо заменить в строке поиска "Enter kewords" на что-то другое и заменить надпись в кнопке "search" на картинку.
В дочерней теме создаю папку woocommerce, в нее помещаю файл product-searchform.php вношу в него изменения и ничего не происходит

Comment: @mxd, мой ответ уже содержал нужную вам информацию. Тем не менее, я указал конкретный файл, который вам нужно скопировать в вашу тему и изменить. Не забывайте, что WooCommerce переведен на русский язык.

Comment: Скопировал файл в свою тему в папку. Стёр вообще всё что было внутри формы. Залил на хостинг - форма стоит на месте и не думает изменяться. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Попробовал менять другие файлы по указанной вами схеме: всё меняется нормально. Но с формой что-то не получается.

Comment: @mxd, Возможно, файл переопределен в самой теме. Сделайте поиск по фразе "Enter keywords" по файлам `*.php` и `*.html`.

Comment: Выводит результаты в файле`mystile\search-form.php`
Скопировал search-form.php в дочернюю тему, поменял разметку. Форма никак не реагирует - висит на  месте и не меняется.

Comment: @mxd, эта форма не имеет отношения к WooCommerce, судя по ее расположению. Править ее нужно напрямую.

Comment: Удалось решить проблему создав собственную форму и написав в widget-woo-search.php путь к ней. Ваша помощь также оказала большое влияние на это.

Comment: @mxd, если мой ответ помог вам решить проблему, пожалуйста, проголосуйте за него и отметьте как верный.